# Windows Azure: Delete disk attached to non-existent VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

Just found out I was taking up - and paying for - a lot of storage due to abandoned disks from long ago deleted VMs. I manged to delete most of them, but now I'm stuck with a set that cannot be deleted as they remain attached to VMs nowhere to be found.

Any ideas how to get rid of these disks, PowerShell tricks maybe?

Comment: If you have recently deleted the VM, for whatever reason, sometimes it takes time for the disk to also be deleted. In this case it will appear in the disks list but the `delete` functionality will appear to be disabled. In the time it took me to read through the answers in this post, the disk disappeared on it's own.

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding correct, Once you delete a Virtual Machine, it delete the service but keep a copy of the VHD image under Disks. So please go to the **Disks** tab under virtual Machine and try to delete it.

If that is not the case, please add a screenshot with error message from where your trying to delete VM.

Comment: No, the VM is long gone, but the disk still seems attached to the - no longer existing - VM. As a result the "Delete" option is greyed, and I'm stuck. I can't delete the VM because it si gone, I can't delete the disk because it is attached to a VM (which is gone), and I can't delete the storage container because it contains data. Therefore I have to pay Microsoft for storing 240 GB of dead disk!

I'm new on Stackoverflow, so I'm not allowed to attach images, but here is a link to a screen shot: http://cl.ly/image/383t2u1q462w

Comment: Hello flensted, At this point if you are still having issue . Your best option is to open a support ticket with Windows Azure Support . http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this that I can see is through `PowerShell`.  I ran into the same problem and here's how I fixed it.  I installed the Azure `PowerShell` extensions and configured my subscription and then my storage account.  Once I did that I then ran this command

```
get-azuredisk | Remove-AzureDisk
```

`Get-azuredisk` will grab all disks  In my case I needed all of them removed.  If you need to do individual then you need to get the name of the disk and then run `remove-azuredisk` with the name switch and specify the disk name to remove it.  That fixed it for me.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the "new" Azure portal. Select Storage Accounts, then click on the storage account" where your none used VHD's are located, Click Blobs under Services, Click vhds under Essentials, search for unwanted vhd and click delete.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use the (2016) web portal to delete orphaned disks in my (classic) storage account. The answers here work, but here is a more detailed walk-through for deleteing these orphaned disks with PowerShell.

#### PowerShell

Download and install PowerShell if you haven't already. ([Install and configure Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/).) Initial steps from this doclink:

- Check that the Azure PowerShell module is available after installing:
  `Get-Module –ListAvailable`
- If the Azure PowerShell module is not listed, you may need to import it:
  `Import-Module Azure`
- Login to Azure Resource Manager:
  `Login-AzureRmAccount`

#### AzurePublishSettingsFile

- Retreive your PublishSettingsFile.
  `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`

  - Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile launches [manage.windowsazure.com](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=powershell) and prompts you to download an XML file that you can be saved anywhere.
  - Reference:  [Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn790375.aspx)
- Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile and specify the path to the file just saved.
  `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile '<your file path>'`

#### Show and Remove Disks

- Show current disks. (Reference: [Azure Storage Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806401.aspx))
  `Get-AzureDisk`
- Quickly remove all disks. (Credit to [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842041/3182836))
  `get-azuredisk | Remove-AzureDisk`
- Or remove disks by name. (Credit to [Remove-AzureDisk Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495255.aspx))
  `Remove-AzureDisk -DiskName disk-name-000000000000000000 -DeleteVHD`

Answer (score 0):

in azure you can erase disks using Azure Storage Explorer.

**If you have a deleted virtual machine and the disks report that they are attached and the command gives you an error:**

Remove-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -DiskName  -Force
output:

Remove-AzDisk: Disk vmname_OsDisk_1_c2116### is attached to VM /subscriptions/###/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmname.

```
ErrorCode: OperationNotAllowed

ErrorMessage: Disk /subscriptions/###/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmname.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : 34731d70-2f9e-4ad1-8eec-4fcb6f55fbd0
```

you can create a generation 1 server to test on the same resource group with the same bug name.

with this you make the "Resource ID" exist for the virtual machine,

and you can now erase the disk by Azure Storage Explorer normally.

This is because Azure does a validation prior to deletion and if the disk is attached, the VM must exist.